# Fetching data from fields other than ObjectId from MongoDb using NodeJS Express server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to use router.get to fetch data from my collection by not having to use the auto-generated _id field. I've been constantly getting the error:

```
"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"xxxxxxxxxx\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Member\""
```

This is my route:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/members/xxxxxxxxxx
```

This is my request function

```
async function getMemberBySSN(req, res, next) {
    let member
    try {
        member = Member.find({ ssn: req.params.ssn }, null);
        if (member == null) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: "Cannot find member" });
        }
    } catch(e) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
    }
    res.member = member
    next();
}
```

Which I call from this route:

```
router.get("/:ssn", getMemberBySSN, (req, res) => {
    res.json(res.member);
})
```

This is the model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Object containing keys for different props in member
const memberSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ssn: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    isJunior: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },
});

//params: name of model in db, the schema that corresponds to the model, the collection in db
module.exports = mongoose.model("Member", memberSchema, "_splurggenMembers");
```

All help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the member by ssn using following code

```
Member.find({ ssn: req.params.ssn}, null);
```

and if you don't want to output the Object id in your response then , use following code in your schema model to delete the id from the output response.

```
memberSchema.set('toJSON', {
  virtuals: true,
  transform: function (doc, ret) {
    delete ret._id;
  }
});
```

Comment: I've updated and slightly adjust my code to yours but I'm still receiving the same error. Like Mongoose is trying to cast the value I'm feeding to router to ObjectId...